# Installing Windows 10 on Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 11

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad

I would like to buy a Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 11 laptop. However, I like Windows 10 and I don't want to upgrade to Windows 11. I can install Windows 10 myself, but I need to be sure that the laptop supports it before I order that laptop. I asked multiple sales representatives whether Gen 11 supports Windows 10 and got conflicting answers.

Does anyone have firsthand experience? i.e. you have a Gen 11 laptop and you actually tried to install Windows 10 on it, and can tell me whether it succeeded or failed? (Success would mean that all the devices on the laptop are recognized and working fine.)

Answer (score 5):

I have a Lenovo X13 13th Gen  Intel and I got it with Window 11 Pro preloaded.

An an option at purchase was to downgrade to Windows 10. So your X1 will run Windows 10 (98%+).

Remember that:  (1) Windows 10 is out of support in 18 months; and (2) Windows 11 Pro properly set up works just fine. There are good features about Windows 11 and the only real adaptability piece is that right click Context has been simplified to what most users need and one needs to use "Show more options" to get the rest of the list.

Most everything else is just mild adaptation.

By all means get Windows 10 if you must, but the X1 will last longer than Windows 10.  I suggest making the move now and save time later.

I have had Windows 11 Pro running for nearly 3 years now.

Answer (score 5):

In the Lenovo Support article
[X1 Carbon 11th Gen - Manual Driver Update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-11th-gen-type-21hm-21hn/downloads/driver-list),
it's possible to find drivers for Windows 10:

[image]

This means that the laptop is supported for Windows 10.

You should have an alternate computer on which you could download
drivers from the above link for the devices which will not work
correctly with the generic Windows 10 drivers.
The alternate computer will be useful especially in case the
network adapter will not work after Windows 10 is installed.
No need to install drivers for devices that work correctly.